# Server handling other requests while executing a function that contains the command asynchio.sleep

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm writing a python server that handles the back end for a webpage that displays flight traffic on a live map. I'm new to programming and don't really understand asychio. Should I be looking at my main function to make my server operate asynchronously? Is it along the lines of loop.create_task?

```
async def retrieve_history(reqICAO,websocket):
    #retrieving history
            await asyncio.wait([websocket.send(message)])
    print (reqHistory)
            

def state_event():
    return json.dumps(AC)


async def notify_state():
    if USERS:  # asyncio.wait doesn't accept an empty list
        message = state_event()
        await asyncio.wait([user.send(message) for user in USERS])


async def notify_test():
    if USERS:  # asyncio.wait doesn't accept an empty list
        for x in range(len(testdata1)):
            #testing stuff here
            await notify_state()
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
            print(str(AC[1]["LAT"]) + "," + str(AC[1]["LON"]))
        await test_reset()
                
async def main(websocket, path):
    # register(websocket) sends user_event() to websocket
    await register(websocket)
    try:
        await websocket.send(state_event())
        async for message in websocket:
            data = json.loads(message)
            if data["action"] == "state":
                await notify_state()
            elif data["action"] == "test":
                await notify_test()
            elif data["action"] == "history":
                await retrieve_history(data["reqICAO"],websocket)
                
            else:
                logging.error("unsupported event: {}", data)
    finally:
        await unregister(websocket)


start_server = websockets.serve(main, "localhost", 6789)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Comment: Please reduce your description and code to the minimum required to explain and demonstrate the problem.

Comment: You may be using asyncio, but you're using it synchronously. You're handling messages one at a time, sequentially.